# Im having problems while running alphacode on ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, bazel

I am using Docker Ubuntu.
I have installed the full dataset(dm-code_contests) to `/tmp` folder and cloned the git repository on `/home folder`(the repository is code_contests). When I try to run `bazel run -c opt \ :print_names_and_sources /tmp/dm-code_contests/code_contests_valid.riegeli`(in /home/code_contests folder), it shows error:

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Repository local_config_python instantiated at:
  /home/code_contests/WORKSPACE:12:10: in <toplevel>
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_deps.bzl:414:21: in grpc_deps
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/grpc_python_deps.bzl:43:21: in grpc_python_deps
Repository rule python_configure defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl:365:35: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_python':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 355, column 35, in _python_autoconf_impl
                _create_single_version_package(
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 304, column 45, in _create_single_version_package
                python_include = _get_python_include(repository_ctx, python_bin)
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 236, column 22, in _get_python_include
                result = _execute(
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 62, column 14, in _execute
                _fail("\n".join([
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 35, column 9, in _fail
                fail("%sPython Configuration Error:%s %s\n" % (red, no_color, msg))
Error in fail: Python Configuration Error: Problem getting python include path for /usr/bin/python3.
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
Is the Python binary path set up right? (See ./configure or /usr/bin/python3.) Is distutils installed? Are Python headers installed? Try installing python-dev or python3-dev on Debian-based systems. Try python-devel or python3-devel on Redhat-based systems.
ERROR: /home/code_contests/WORKSPACE:12:10: fetching python_configure rule //external:local_config_python: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 355, column 35, in _python_autoconf_impl
                _create_single_version_package(
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 304, column 45, in _create_single_version_package
                python_include = _get_python_include(repository_ctx, python_bin)
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 236, column 22, in _get_python_include
                result = _execute(
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 62, column 14, in _execute
                _fail("\n".join([
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 35, column 9, in _fail
                fail("%sPython Configuration Error:%s %s\n" % (red, no_color, msg))
Error in fail: Python Configuration Error: Problem getting python include path for /usr/bin/python3.
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
Is the Python binary path set up right? (See ./configure or /usr/bin/python3.) Is distutils installed? Are Python headers installed? Try installing python-dev or python3-dev on Debian-based systems. Try python-devel or python3-devel on Redhat-based systems.
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/24a36d3f089e715b642fd688d4461183/external/com_google_riegeli/python/riegeli/records/BUILD:8:13: @com_google_riegeli//python/riegeli/records:record_writer_cc depends on @local_config_python//:python_headers in repository @local_config_python which failed to fetch. no such package '@local_config_python//': Python Configuration Error: Problem getting python include path for /usr/bin/python3.
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
Is the Python binary path set up right? (See ./configure or /usr/bin/python3.) Is distutils installed? Are Python headers installed? Try installing python-dev or python3-dev on Debian-based systems. Try python-devel or python3-devel on Redhat-based systems.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:print_names_and_sources' failed; build aborted:
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.701s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (49 packages loaded, 348 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (49 packages loaded, 348 targets configured)
    Fetching @com_google_absl; Cloning tags/20211102.0 of https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
root@c89a94de94ce://home/code_contests# bazel run -c opt  \ :print_names_and_sources /tmp/dm-code_contests/code_contests
_valid.riegeli
ERROR: Skipping ' :print_names_and_sources': no such package ' ': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
 - /home/code_contests/
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package ' ': BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
 - /home/code_contests/
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.174s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Im new to Ubuntu(as well as bazel).
 So how can I fix this error and run the project?
link to the source code: https://github.com/deepmind/code_contests

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your gcc is the latest version.

For python2 you should install it like this:

```
#Remove bazel and reinstall
bazel clean --expunge
rm -rf ~/.cache/bazel
```

To re-install follow this instruction

```
#Install python2 dependency
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-dev
```

For a detailed explanation kindly refer to this [document](https://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Competition-Level%20Code%20Generation%20with%20AlphaCode.pdf). Thank you!